# need passing two parameters getting with one parameter value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my code. I am not able to get my desired output. I should pass parameters and retrieve either with `CustomerCode` or with `CustomerName`. Please help me. Thanks in advance and below I placed my sp

```
    protected void txtsearch_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRedemItem", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 
        (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text== "int" ? Convert.ToInt32(txtkey2.Text) :(object)DBNull.Value); 
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = 
        (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text == "string" ? txtkey2.Text : (object)DBNull.Value);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Session["CustomerName"] = dt;
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            Label10.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ItemCode"].ToString();
            Label11.Text = dt.Rows[0]["CustomerName"].ToString();
            Label12.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PointsNeeded"].ToString();
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }
```

--my sp

```
alter Proc spRedemItem
(
@CustomerCode int=null,
@CustomerName nvarchar(50)=null
)
as
begin
select b.ItemCode,a.CustomerName,c.PointsNeeded from CustomerProfMain a
left join tb_Product b on a.CustomerCode=b.ItemCode
left join tb_RedemptionProducts c on b.Product_ID=c.ID
where (@CustomerCode is null or CustomerCode=@CustomerCode) or (@CustomerName is null or CustomerName=@CustomerName)
end
```

Comment: You aren't passing null values to your SP, but texts comming from the same source (txtKey2.Txt). So both your parameters *have* values and your query fails.

Comment: i replaced this with another condition also sir it is not working condition is  cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text== "int" ? Convert.ToInt32(txtkey2.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value);
               cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text == "string" ? txtkey2.Text : (object)DBNull.Value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using,

```
where (@CustomerCode is null or CustomerCode=@CustomerCode) 
OR (@CustomerName is null or CustomerName=@CustomerName)
```

you can try changing your WHERE clause like,

```
where (@CustomerCode is null or CustomerCode=@CustomerCode) 
AND
(@CustomerName is null or CustomerName=@CustomerName)
```

Comment: Is your SP returning desired output in SSMS?

Comment: i replaced with this condition then also am not getting sir.Condition is             cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text== "int" ? Convert.ToInt32(txtkey2.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value); cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = (DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text == "string" ? txtkey2.Text : (object)DBNull.Value);

Comment: Is datatable `dt` getting the required output?

Comment: yes sir.if try with 1st parameter it is working if i try with the 2nd parameter its not working.

Comment: Can you try changing `GridView1.DataBind();` with, `GridView1.DataSource = ds; GridView1.DataBind();`.